# Selecting id's that has at least one observation pre and post in R

Tags: r, filter

I am trying to filter the ID's that has at least one observation in both pre period and post period each. For example, I select ID 1 as that has pre1,2 and post 1, also ID 3 for the same reason. But, ID2,5 does not have post period observations and ID4 does not have pre period observations so those ID's(2, 4, and 5) are dropped.

I am currently divide the sample into pre and post parts and merge them by intersection using merge(pre, post, by='ID', all=FALSE). However, it gives me wrong result so I was wondering if there is other ways to do this. I would appreciate it if you help me with this. Thank you!

| ID | Year |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pre1 |
| 1 | pre2 |
| 1 | post1 |
| 2 | pre2 |
| 2 | pre3 |
| 3 | pre1 |
| 3 | post1 |
| 4 | post2 |
| 4 | post3 |
| 5 | pre1 |
| 5 | pre2 |

Answer (score 0):

We can remove the digits with `str_remove` and `filter` the number of distinct elements after grouping by 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(n_distinct(str_remove(Year, "\\d+")) > 1) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
     ID Year 
  <int> <chr>
1     1 pre1 
2     1 pre2 
3     1 post1
4     3 pre1 
5     3 post1
```

---

Or another option is to use `str_detect`

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(any(str_detect(Year, 'pre')), any(str_detect(Year, 'post'))) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
     ID Year 
  <int> <chr>
1     1 pre1 
2     1 pre2 
3     1 post1
4     3 pre1 
5     3 post1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L), Year = c("pre1", "pre2", "post1", "pre2", "pre3", "pre1", 
"post1", "post2", "post3", "pre1", "pre2")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was really helpful and I appreciate you guys' help

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it using a tidy method to build a list of ID values:

```
ids<-data%>%
  mutate(prefix=str_remove_all(Year, "[:digit:]"))%>% #remove numbers
  select(ID, prefix)%>% #Get rid of Year column
  distinct()%>% #de duplicate to one row for each ID Year type
  group_by(ID)%>% #group by ID
  summarise(frequency=n())%>% #count how many rows there are
  filter(frequency>1)%>% #if 2 rows 1 is post, one is pre
  select(ID)%>%  #select only ID column
  as_vector() #create a vector of ID's meeting requirements

data%>%filter(ID %in% ids) #subset data based on ID's above
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This looks like a lot of code, but after you figure out how to get the numbers out of the Year column it is simply tidyverse work.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDiRc.png